# 403 Forbidden Error Superset Test Connection

Tags: apache-superset

I have a Superset, while deployed on PROD, I get Auth error whenever I try to Add any database.
As I test I tried Test Connection with Example database that also give the same error.
Surprisingly there is no error in any backend logs

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the right driver installed in the running superset environment

Comment: Found the issue. It was AWS WAF which was blocking the request.